# How can I remove a CMS system(php-fusion) from an FTP server?

Tags: php, ftp, web, content-management-system

I have a cms website(php fusion) on ftp server but I would like to change to a simple php website, that I wrote myself. Can I remove the cms system? If yes, how? Just delete the folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just deleting the folder (and required database files) will indeed completely delete the CMS.

Note that the index.php must be in the same location though, so if your cms is installed in `~/www` you will need to keep the `www` folder.

Comment: so delete not the folder itself, only just the files inside the folders?

Comment: Because I have a public_html folder and a example.com folder. If I click the public_html goes the same folder, what is the example.com....
so can I delete the example.com folder, and delete all files in public_html folder and load my files to public_html?